# Can AS2 ISAID for a sender change over period

Tags: edi

Is it possible that AS2 ISAID for a particular entity get changed over the period. If I want to use AS2 ISAID as decision point in my application then will it be safe?

Thanks in advance
Kaushik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS2 identifiers and ISA identifiers are mutually exclusive.  They are two separate things.  These identifiers can be created arbitrarily and then dispensed to trading partners.

For example, my ISA ID is KEYSOURCE.  MY AS2 ID is ZZKEYSOURCE.  These have no reason to change, and should be unique to my organization.  Neither should change.

The only time I've seen them change is if there was a platform change, or if the company was purchased and needed to change identifiers to reflect their branding.